# HMM Model Selection

Tags: model-selection, hidden-markov-model

What is the process for selecting a model for an HMM?  Say the data is time sequences, where each time sequence represents a class. I can used Baum-Welch to train, but I don't know how to determine the model.

Let the model selection involve finding the optimal number of states and the possible transitions between states.  In other words which transitions are allowed, not what the probabilities are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have multiple candidates of the model, $\mathcal{M}_1$, $\mathcal{M}_2$,$\ldots$,$\mathcal{M}_n$. For each model, you can consider Cross-validation to evaluate the performance. You can evaluate the likelihood of the model using forward and backward algorithm. And use the criteria to do the model selection using the likelihood you just calculated.

For example, the criteria of model selection can be:

- AIC = log L + 2*k,
- BIC = log L + k * log N

where L is the likelihood of P(observation; parameter), and N is the number of parameters.

There some discussion about the model selection and overfitting issue in Section 7 of [Ghahramani (2001)](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/papers/ijprai.pdf).